# How can I fetch a single model from the server

Tags: ember.js

How can I fetch a single model from the server using Ember Data?
For example, I have url for my server api `localhost:8080/rest/setting`, and respond is JSON object
        `{
        "siteName": "lala",
        "siteUrl": "blabla"
        }`
In the result I want to use this model for rendering in my template.

Comment: "with using Ember Data"?  Is that a typo: "without" or just "using Ember Data"

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you meant to say "...can I fetch a single model from the server without using Ember Data", in which case of course you can! Just use jQuery to get your data. For example:

```
App.ExampleRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return Ember.$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'localhost:8080/rest/setting',
      dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh, I mean "using Ember Data" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Setting = DS.Model.extend({
  sitename: DS.attr()
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:8080',  // this isn't necessary, since it'll use the current server's host
  namespace: 'rest' // this is appended to your current web server host http://server/rest
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('foo', {path:'/:foo_id'});
});

App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
     // if param.foo_id is 1 then
     // this would be http://localhost:8080/rest/setting/1
     return this.get('store').find('setting', params.foo_id);  
  }
});
```

your JSON should come back in this format:

```
{ setting: { "siteName": "lala", "siteUrl": "blabla" } }
```

If you want it to be in a different format you need to use a serializer and massage the data into the format Ember is expecting: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but a setting object hasn't id property, the setting is a single model for all application